# How to remove the install/unistall receiver on killing the applicationfrom multitask pane/force closing the app?

Tags: android, events, broadcastreceiver, react-native

I have written a plugin in the react-native to send the events to Javascript (package name of installed application) on installing of new app or unistalling(package name of uninstalled application) of existing application.

The problem i'm facing is, when the i kill the application(removed from multitask pane), the receiver will be keep on listening to the install/uninstall event. This says unfortunately the app has closed.

Please find the code i have written as below:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context context;
    private static AppListModule module;

    public MyReceiver(AppListModule module) {
        this.module = module;
    }

    public MyReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        this.context = context;

        // This condition will be called when package removed
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {
            String packageName = intent.getDataString();
            Log.e(" BroadcastReceiver ", "onReceive called "
                    + " PACKAGE_REMOVED ");

            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            params.putString("message", packageName);
            this.module.sendEvent(this.module.getReactApplicationContextModule(), "InstallUninstall", params);
        }
        // This condition will be called when package installed
        else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {
            String packageName = intent.getDataString();
            Log.e(" BroadcastReceiver ", "onReceive called " + "PACKAGE_ADDED");
            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            params.putString("message", packageName);
            if(this.module!=null) {
                this.module.sendEvent(this.module.getReactApplicationContextModule(), "InstallUninstall", params);
            }
        }
    }
```

The only question i'm having is how to remove the receiver when i kill the app. Please help in this regard.

Setting MyReceiver.java

```
  public void setData(ReactApplicationContext mcontext, AppListModule module) {
        context = mcontext;
        this.module = module;
        this.eventsReceiver = new MyReceiver(this.module);
    }
```

Comment: How do you create `MyReceiver`? Show the code and indicate the situation where/when this is done.

Comment: @DavidWasser i have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to keep a reference to `MyReceiver` somewhere so that you can use that to unregister it. I assume that you are creating and registering `MyReceiver` in an `Activity`. If so, you should be able to unregister it in `onDestroy()`:

```
context.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

You need to make sure that you call `unregisterReceiver()` on the same `Context` that you used to call `registerReceiver()`.

---

Also, as a safety net, you should check that `this.module != null` in `MyReceiver.onReceive()`. If it is `null`, just ignore the call to `onReceive()` and do nothing. This will prevent your app from crashing.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it and let you know